# Theorem regarding union of spaces and quotient space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Is there a theorem something like if $A=B\cup C$, then $A\simeq B/\partial C$ .

($\simeq$ refers to homotopy equivalent).

($A$, $B$, $C$ are spaces, and $\partial C$ refers to the boundary of $C$).

I forgot the exact statement of the theorem, I would like to recall it but I have forgotten the source and the name as well. There may well be some conditions/amendments to the theorem stated above.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is $\partial C\subseteq B$ in order to make $B/\partial C$?

Comment: @FabioLucchini Yes, I think we need $\partial C\subseteq B$.

Comment: Consider the case where $A = B = C$; then you're asking for $C$ to be homotopy equivalent to $C/\partial C$ and there's no reason for this to be true, e.g. if $C$ is a disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a topological space does not have a boundary, only manifolds do. Here is a situation that might ring a bell:

Take a subset $D\subset B$, and let $C$ be the cone on $D$ (i.e., $C=D\times [0,1]/D\times \{1\}$), and identify $D$ with $D\times \{0\}\subset C$. Then $B\cup C \simeq B/D$.

In the case when $D$ is a sphere, then $C$ is a disc and $D=\partial C$, so you have that $B\cup C \simeq B/\partial C$.

Comment: This construcion appears in the Puppe sequence $D\to B\to B/D$. To show that it gives rise to a long exact sequence in (co)homology one uses that $B\cup C\simeq B/D$.